# Sqlalchemy convert scalar objects to list

Tags: python, orm, sqlalchemy

Hi I want to convert an instance object (scalar objects) returned by "filter()" method to a list.

Is it possible to get a list similar to a list returned by "all()" method.

Are there any methods ?

Answer (score 0):

When you run the query

```
In [3]: session.query(User).all()
2012-01-05 16:45:42,553 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.base.Engine BEGIN (implicit)
2012-01-05 16:45:42,554 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.base.Engine SELECT user.username AS user_username
FROM user
```

Bug if you run the filter

```
In [4]: session.query(MPA).filter(User.username=='test')
Out[4]: <sqlalchemy.orm.query.Query object at 0x25d12d0>
```

So if you want list then you can use this

```
In [5]: list (session.query(User).filter(User.username=='test'))
```

But internally it will call `.all()` method.

Answer (score 0):

[`Query.filter(criterion)`](http://www.sqlalchemy.org/docs/orm/query.html?highlight=filter#sqlalchemy.orm.query.Query.filter) method does not return instance objects. From the docs:

> apply the given filtering criterion to the query and **return the newly resulting `Query`**

[`Query.all()`](http://www.sqlalchemy.org/docs/orm/query.html?highlight=all#sqlalchemy.orm.query.Query.all), on the other hand, returns the results. From the docs:

> **Return the results** represented by this `Query` as a list.

---

To solve your task, just add `.all()` to the query with the `filter`, which will **execute** the query:

```
my_session.query(...).filter(...).all()
```